# Meaning of "observable scales" in cosmology

Tags: cosmology

This is something everyone reads about in cosmology texts or research in cosmic inflation- there is a cosmological pivot scale $k_{\star}=0.05$ or $0.002\;\text{Mpc}^{-1}$ at which relevant parameters like the spectral index and amplitude of primordial fluctuations are measured. I have a fundamental problem understanding what observationally people are looking for when talk about the observational scales.

In terms of primordial fluctuations generated during inflation, I understand that different modes corresponding to different wavelenghts exit the horizon at different times with the observable scales being one of the earliest to exit. What are experimentalists probing when they determine what these observational scales are?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the experiment. Space-based CMB missions like the Planck sureveyor probe scales $10^{-4}$ to $0.1$ Mpc$^{-1}$, while large scale structure surveys probe from around $10^{-2}$ to $0.3$ Mpc$^{-1}$.  Lyman alpha forest measurements can reach ever smaller scales, around $1$ Mpc$^{-1}$, while future probes of the 21cm line of neutral hydrogen might resolve down to $100$ Mpc$^{-1}$.  Lastly, future measurements of CMB spectral distortion might reveal information about the power spectrum on scales $50$ to $10^4$ Mpc$^{-1}$.